# User Defined Function not found

Tags: google-bigquery, bigquery-udf

I have created a permanent UDF function to validate emails like this:

```sql
create or replace function 
`project-name`.udf_library.is_valid_email(text STRING)
returns Bool
as (REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, r"valid_regex"));
```

and have tested  it with the following query and works like a charm:

```sql
with emails as
(select 'alberto@example.com' as email
union all
select 'foobar' as email
union all
select 'disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com' as email
union all
select '"john..doe"@example.org' as email
union all
select 'i_like_underscore@but_its_not_allow_in_this_part.example.com' as email)
select email, `project-name`.udf_library.is_valid_email(email) as validEmail from emails
```

```
Row email                                                   validEmail 
1   alberto@example.com                                           true
2   foobar                                                       false
3   disposable.style.email.with+symbol@example.com                true
4   "john..doe"@example.org                                       true
5   i_like_underscore@but_its_not_allow_in_this_part.example.com false
```

But when I query a table and try to use the function like this

```sql
SELECT email, `project-name`.udf_library.is_valid_email(email) as validEmail 
FROM `project-name.Mydataset.MyTable`
```

I get this:

Function not found: `project-name`.udf_library.is_valid_email at [1:15]

It does work if I  create it as temp function but that defeats the whole purpose of having permanent UDFs

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check location of dataset `project-name.Mydataset` and `project-name.udf_library`, they have to sit in same region for your last query to work.

The query using `WITH` to prepare data works because it is routed to the region where the UDF sits. The last query probably got routed to where the data is.

Comment: you are right - I created my dataset by mistake in US region. Thanks